A cutoff function which the constant of its derivatives is independent of the dimension
In Page 842 of Function Spaces and Partial Differential Equations written by Ali Taheri, the author claims that there is a cutoff function which the constant of its derivatives is independent of the dimension. Indeed, let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $0<\rho<r$ with $B(x,r)\subset\Omega$ (i.e. the ball is centered at $x$ with radius $r$), then there exists a cutoff function $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, such that
(1) $\eta=1$ on the Ball $B(x,\rho)$,
(2) $\eta=0$ on $\Omega\setminus B(x,r)$,
(3) $0\leqslant \eta\leqslant 1$ on $\Omega$,
(4) $|\nabla\eta|\leqslant \frac{2}{r-\rho}\quad \text{on }\quad \Omega$.
Usually, many books claim that in (4) the constant depends on the dimension $n$ and the order $|\alpha|$ of $|D^\alpha\eta|$ (i.e. in (4) $|\alpha|=1$).  I have seen in other books that claims the constant can also be independent of the order $|\alpha|$. Unfortunately, they don't give details on how to construct the required cutoff functions.
My Question: how to construct such a cutoff function that the constant of its derivative is independent of the dimension and the order (i.e. satisfies (4))?

I am sure how to construct a cut off function that satisfies (1)-(3). Indeed, let
\begin{equation}
  \phi(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \exp(-\frac{1}{x}),         &x>0,\\
    0,                          &x\leqslant 0. 
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then define the function
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\dfrac{f(r-|x|)}{f(r-|x|)+f(|x|-\rho)},
\end{equation}
where now $|x|=(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^\frac{1}{2}$. I tried to calculate the gradient of $f$, but it seemed complicated. So I am not sure whether $f$ satisfies (4).
I wish to know more details. Thank you!

Just a rough idea: If you were to take linear segments satisfying this (i.e. being $1$ on the boundary of $B(x,\rho)$ and $0$ on $B(x,r)$), you would be able to achieve $|\nabla \eta|\le \frac{1}{r-\rho}$ because this would just be the slope of your function on $B(x,r) \backslash B(x,\rho)$. If you now mollify this function in order to be smooth, the gradient might become slightly bigger, that's why we take the factor $2$. You could exchange $2$ for any number strictly larger than $1$.

If you would consider higher order derivatives, they would grow with $( r-\rho)^{- |\alpha|}$. As soon as you take a different $l^p$-norm on $\mathbb R^d$ do measure $|\nabla u|$ you get an dimension dependence.
